# Uninstalling skype

Tags: 12.10, uninstall, skype

I installed skype on my ubuntu 12.10 computer, but after opening the program I discovered that I can't log in with facebook, witch is my skype account. so i'm trying to uninstall it. I followed this guide to install it 
http://www.tecmint.com/install-skype-4-1-in-ubuntu-xubuntu-linux-mint/
and used the 12.10 option

Comment: Please [edit] the question to use proper capitalization on `i` and replace `witch` with `which` so that English translating software can parse this question accurately.

Answer (score 14):

You need to know the name of the package that skype was installed as part of. Enter the following:

```
dpkg -S skype
```

This should list all the files installed from packages containing the word skype. The name at the beginning of the line before the colon is the package name. Once you've identified the package name you should just be able to run

```
dpkg -r package-name-here
```

Comment: I used `apt-get purge remove skype`, which seemed to uninstall everything.  However, when I list packages using `dpkg -S skype` I see about 100 entries... I'm confused about what's happened.  Even after purging / uninstalling the skype window has popped up again.

Comment: if u got 'ubuntu requested operation requires superuser privilege', then simply add 'sudo' before command, and it will be done.

Answer (score 7):

This worked on 12.04 LTS.

```
sudo apt-get remove skype
```

Answer (score 4):

I am sure the terminal commands in the other answers work, but if you prefer a gui way:

- If you don't have already install synaptic package manager via the software center.
- Now open synaptic package manager, and enter your password.
- In the quick filter search bar type 'skype' look for a package which is currently installed with skype in the name.
- Right click on it and click 'mark for removal' or 'mark for complete removal' (if you also want to delete the configuration files).
- Now hit 'apply' and skype will be removed

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin
rm -rf ~/.skype
```

Answer (score 0):

- `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop`

  - `Exec=skype %U`
  - `Exec=env LC_ALL=C skype %U`

Use these commands. It is gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

My case is something different, here i run two commands :-

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep 'skype'
```

output is :- skype-bin:i386 install

So, to remove i run :-

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove skype-bin:i386
```

and after that i remove ".Skype" from home directory